# Why by the mitzvah of chanukka we must light at both doors so other wont be suspicious

Tags: halacha, chanuka

#### The Halacha is:

That if one has more then one door at his house, he must light the menorah at all doors... The reason is because others might think that someone lives here but didn't light the menorah...

#### So my question is:

Since when (other then by tfilla - when passing a shul) do we have to be yotza all chashasous and light at all entrances (if one has) Why and where else do we find such a chumra? and what do we care if/what others will think that I didn't light...

Do I have to show everyone that I did this or that mitzva?

Comment: Hi adardesign and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I'm afraid I don't follow your question exactly: isn't there somewhat of a general rule (or at least reasonable to say) that we should avoid looking suspicious in public? In what cases do you see a permission to do that such that Chanukkah would then be the exception?

Comment: I think this question needs to be fleshed out more, detailing the exact case when one must light at two doorways and the reasons given for this (with relevant source references).

Comment: @Lazer, you are right, i tried to explain a little more.. I will also try to bring relevant source references... Thanks!

Comment: The halacha as you have stated is not really accurate. No one says you need to light a second menorah by your back door or side door, etc. It is only in very limited circumstances that this issue exists.

Comment: @LazerA true, but my question is still on for these very limited circumstances... no?

Comment: Probably, however, being that the halacha only applies to a very limited circumstance, it is problematic to attempt to ask about the application of this principle in completely different areas, without first clarifying what the exact case is and exactly why the halacha is what it is in that case and not in other cases involving Chanukah neiros. In other words, before you can ask why we don't apply this principle to other mitzvos, you first need to clarify what this principle actually *is*, and how it is applied to this specific mitzva.

Answer (score 2):

The following is what I thought:

Because the main purpose for lighting the menorah is for "Pirsuma nusa"* therefor anything that leads to suspicion is the opposite of pisrsum hanes.

*Its one of the only mitzvous that one should even sell his belongings..

Comment: If you’d like you can mark your own answer as correct.